# nightly build and virtual machines

Tags: msbuild, virtual-machine, build-server, nightly-build

At my place we are writing server side applications (WCF services) and we are looking forward automate the installation and run it in our nightly build process...
Moreover, we are looking forward installing it again and again on different servers...

We are searching for:

1. what is the best tool for nightly build?
   (we are currently using TeamCity, but it is only good for CI not for the Nighty Build requirements)
2. Is there anyone who build its solutions\projects and install  them on Virtual-Machines? 
   (Can you attach\link some automated code for this installation?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [FinalBuilder](http://www.finalbuilder.com/finalbuilder.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

TeamCity is a great tool. It supports scheduling a build like CC.NET for nightly builds. What kind of issues are you having with it?

Comment: As far as I see this TC good enough for CI not for NihgtlyBuild.
Because we cannot configure to install windows-services, install on remote machines, of course we can use Msbuild but it will be hard to write all of this.

Answer (score 1):

Try NAnt for the build:
http://nant.sourceforge.net/

and CruiseControl.NET for the continuous integration:
http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Welcome+to+CruiseControl.NET

both are open source :-D

Answer (score 1):

TeamCity will cope with nightly builds just as well as CC.Net etc.

Your comment

> As far as I see this TC good enough
>   for CI not for NihgtlyBuild. Because
>   we cannot configure to install
>   windows-services, install on remote
>   machines, of course we can use Msbuild
>   but it will be hard to write all of
>   this.

It isn't particularly difficult to do any of this (IMO of course) using [Microsoft.SDC.Tasks](http://blogs.msdn.com/csell/archive/2006/07/12/microsoft-sdc-tasks-new-version-released.aspx)